# How to expand component to fill form window?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

There doesn't seem to be a way to easily snap my excel-type object to the border of the parent window.  I've searched through all the properties and cannot seem to find what I'm looking for.

In the form editor, `FormResults.cs [Design]` in my case, in the form properties (an instance of `System.Windows.Forms.Form`), I have the property `WindowState` set to `Maximized`.  That opens the windows to the whole desktop, but still does nothing for scaling the element with the window.

[image]

Comment: `WindowState` sets the state of whole form. Here you need to set `Anchor` or `Dock` property of control present in the form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the `DockStyle` of the control to `fill`. See [DockStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dockstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) . This should ensure the control fills all the available space of the parent control.

> All the control's edges are docked to the all edges of its containing
>   control and sized appropriately.